# How to close a Tkinter Dialog box successfully and store variables?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button

I have a python code (my main code) that I want to add a GUI on top off using Tkinter. The main code currently has two directories that I have hard-coded in the main code. Basically that code moves files from one directory (input_folder) to another directory (output_folder). However, I want to create a GUI that enables users to click two buttons for browsing the input and output folder directories.

I am using Jupyter Notebooks and the issue is that after I select the input_folder it doesn't close the dialog box even after using the destroy command and the "asterisk" next to the cell doesn't change to a number which would normally represent that a command was successfully executed. If everything closes successfully then both the input_folder and output_folder will have the correct directories stored to those variables and my "main code" will work perfectly after that.

Here's my Tkinter code if anyone can help I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

```
# Import the required Libraries
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile

# Create an instance of tkinter frame
win = Tk()

# Set the geometry of tkinter frame
win.geometry("700x350")

def open_file():
   input_folder = askdirectory(title = 'Select Folder')
   print(input_folder)
   win.destroy()

# Add a Label widget
label = Label(win, text="Click the Button to browse the Files", font=('Georgia 13'))
label.pack(pady=10)



# Create a Button
ttk.Button(win, text="Browse", command=open_file).pack(pady=20)


#ttk.Button(win, text = "Quit", command=exit).pack(pady = 30)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: `global input_folder` should do

Comment: Where would that go though?

Answer (score 0):

In the `open_file()` function, at the very first, add `global input_folder`.

[Learn more about global and local variables in python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/)

Also, just a small suggestion - avoid importing everything (`*`) from a module and importing a module multiple times. You imported `tkinter.filedialog` almost 3 times.